# "df -h" command puts line breaks in output. How do I fix?

Tags: disk, fstab, disk-usage, disk-management

My "df -h"  command on my Linux box has some devices with longer names and so the "df -h" output has line breaks (or tabs??) in it, which makes it difficult to parse the output in a script.

Does anyone know how I can suppress the linebreaks so that the latter of the following outputs is what I get:

```
[root@me ~]# df -kh
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      3.9G  404M  3.3G  11% /
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol05
                      3.9G  442M  3.3G  12% /home
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol04
                      3.9G  261M  3.5G   7% /var
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol03
                      3.9G  137M  3.6G   4% /tmp
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol02
                      7.8G  3.6G  3.8G  49% /usr
```

And the desired format is:

```
[root@me ~]# df -kh
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00   3.9G  404M  3.3G  11% /
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol05   3.9G  442M  3.3G  12% /home
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol04   3.9G  261M  3.5G   7% /var
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol03   3.9G  137M  3.6G   4% /tmp
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol02   7.8G  3.6G  3.8G  49% /usr
```

Comment: I can't test this because my drive paths aren't huge like yours. Try `df -Pkh`

Comment: @user606723: why do not put it in an answer?

Comment: I did just now. =p. I didn't put it in an answer at first because it was a blatant guess from looking at the man file for two seconds.

Comment: The use of `-h` and `-k` together is pointless as they contradict each other and the last one given "wins" (i.e. `df -hk` gives _1024 blocks_ output while `df -kh` gives _human readable_ output).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try: `df -Pkh`

The P stands for "portable", and will force it to follow POSIX standard output.
I have a hunch will fix any clever formatting that df tries to do.

In the future when you try to solve problems like these, try `man df` and see if you can find anything that looks like it might work... cause thats what I did =)

Comment: Ack. I was using "df --help" rather than "man df" . thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

```
 df -Ph | awk '{printf "%-35s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-5s%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'
```